# StackOverFlow Exception while Writing the Object Graph in to XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, stack-overflow

I am trying to Write an object stream into a XAML file but i end up in StackoverFlowException .
In the CallStack i could see "The maximum number of stack frames supported by Visual Studio has been exceeded"

This is the piece of code i'm trying to execute.

```
StreamWriter xamlStream =new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite("a.xaml"));
string myXaml = System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(objectInstance);
xamlStream.Write(myXaml);
```

Thanks ...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Must be that the objectInstance contains cyclic references and your writer doesn't support them.

Comment: Yes i do have cyclic references, do i have any other way to achieve this.

Comment: You can do the serialization manually. Replace the cyclic references with some kind of ID, like a GUID and then use that to set the references again when reading the object.